# how to load rope: installed it, but failing to load it

Tags: ocaml, opam

I installed rope with opam and verified that it's available:

`rope           0.5  Ropes ("heavyweight strings")`

But how to load it?? [The documentation](http://rope.forge.ocamlcore.org/) states I should use `#load "rope.cma";;` but this gives me the message `Cannot find file rope.cma.`

Can someone please tell me what's the incantation for loading it??

Comment: Use #list when you have topfind activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load `rope` into interactive session use `topfind`

```
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "rope";;
```

To compile your programs with `rope`

```
ocamlbuild -pkg rope your_program.native
```

or alternatively

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -package rope your_program.ml -o your_program
```